# Analyse emails to find how many emails per subject per day

Tags: email, gmail

I have been searching for a tool that lets me know how many emails I have received per day for a particular subject. I regularly get emails with that subject, and I want to analyse how many I have got daily.

Are there any tools out there that can do this? I can't find any.

Thank you.

Comment: What client do you use to receive email? Should be a simple search filter.

Comment: I am using gmail.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

One option as you are using Gmail, there are a lot of [advanced search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) techniques you can use. This will allow you to get only the items you want and analyse from there easily enough.

For example

`subject:"My Subject" after:2016/01/08`

would return all emails with 'My Subject' as the subject, after 12:00 today.

For other days you could use

`subject:"My Subject" after:2016/01/07 before:2016/01/08`

Allowing you to get the emails for 07/01/2016.

It will tell you in the top right how many emails matched your criteria.